# A proper way in a nodejs app to instantiate rabbit and redis

Tags: node.js, redis, rabbitmq

I'm building a nodejs app that instead of http will use rabbitMq and Redis as a way to communicate with the outside world.

I can found many examples about how to instantiate one and the other but, What would be a proper way to open both connections and wait for both to be ready before the real application work can start?

You may see from this questions that I'm a newbie on this ;)

Edit: code sample to make it easy to understand

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
var redis = require('redis');

var clientRedis = redis.createClient(redisPort, ipQueue, {});

clientRedis.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Redis connected.');
    connectQueue();
});

function connectQueue() {
    amqp.connect("amqp://" + ipQueue, function (err, conn) {
        console.log("Test app started...");
        if (err != null) { bail(err); }
        conn.createChannel(function (err, ch) {
            if (err != null) console.log("ERRROR:" + err);
            ch.assertQueue(QueueInstructionsSet, { durable: false });
            workers.startWorkers(4);
            channel = ch;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, I think it is not something that should make the application. 
Because if you want to check if redis works or if rabbitMQ works in your computer, when you move your application to one server, maybe this check doesn't work.

This services are independents of your application, and if your app crashes because one of this services are down, it is what is expected.

I use Redis and RabbitMQ for the same purpose in my project and I can explain you what I do.

**For redis** I use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis). It's very clear to use.
You just have to make sure you have the Redis server running when you run your application.

**For rabbitMQ** I use my own npm package, [nibi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nibi). Also it works with amazon queues. I make this library because when I started I did not find an easy way to work with queues using nodeJs.
Again, you just have to make sure you have the RabbitMQ server running when you run your application.

**Edit:**

If you really need to do some cheks before run your app, you can use a  [prestart and start script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) using npm.
It's very easy in your package.json make something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "node ./check-your-enviroment.js",
  "start": "node ./index.js"
}
```

So when you run your app with npm start, run your "checker" first and then run the main program.

Comment: your reply has some interesting points and I do use packages like this. What I wanted to achieve is that once both systems are up and ready then application process can start

Comment: In this case, maybe you are looking for something like [prestart and start script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)